# How to show edit and delete buttons on datatables when right clicking a row?

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables, contextmenu, right-click

I am using [datatables](https://datatables.net). Is it possible to show working edit and delete buttons on right click like the example [here](https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/demo.html)?
The only working example I found is [this](http://live.datatables.net/caderego/100/embed). But it is not what I am trying to achieve.

Example for click events: https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/events_live.html

Comment: working edit and delete buttons?

Comment: why not use the first example then?

Comment: as I said I don't know jquery and not sure how to integrate jQuery-contextMenu with datatables. At the moment I have checkboxes all of them have different id and I have to click the checkbox to delete or edit a row. But I would like to use this feature. I would appreciate at least if you can tell me how to get id on click any row

Comment: It seems to be exactly what you want, you just need to add some icons, some other text and linking them to the actions you want to perform.

Comment: thanks David for the reply. how I am going to assign the id's on right click?

Comment: @hijacker83, can you setup a small fiddle that looks like your setup with checkboxes? Here is a starting point -> **http://jsfiddle.net/0f9Ljfjr/895/**

Comment: sure! I will. Allow me 10 minutes.

Comment: @davidkonrad here is the jsfiddle link -> http://jsfiddle.net/0f9Ljfjr/899/ I am not sure it would remove the row as it is pure html. I only copied and pasted the source which has been generated from my php script. Thanks so much for your help. –

Comment: He wants to use the context menu to edit or delete rows, based on where the mouse pointer is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could init the contextmenu in the `drawCallback` handler, and retrieve the `id` from the clicked row in `$.contextMenu`'s own callback :

```
drawCallback : function() {
  $.contextMenu({
        selector: 'tbody tr td', 
        callback: function(key, options) {
            var id = options.$trigger[0].parentElement.id;
            var m = "clicked: " + key + ' ' + id;
            window.console && console.log(m) || alert(m); 
            /*
             switch (key) {
               case 'delete' :
                 yourDeleteMethod(id); break;
               case 'edit' :
                 yourEditMethod(id); break;
               ...
              }
            */ 
        },
        items: {
            "edit": {name: "Edit", icon: "edit"},
            "cut": {name: "Cut", icon: "cut"},
           copy: {name: "Copy", icon: "copy"},
            "paste": {name: "Paste", icon: "paste"},
            "delete": {name: "Delete", icon: "delete"},
            "sep1": "---------",
            "quit": {name: "Quit", icon: function(){
                return 'context-menu-icon context-menu-icon-quit';
            }}
        }
    });
},
```

updated fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/0f9Ljfjr/900/**

Since the selector is set to `tbody tr td` the `id` will always could be found by `options.$trigger[0].parentElement.id`. Now you just need to respond to what ever actions you need, and call your own methods with the retrieved `id`.

Comment: woaaww! that's awsome. Thank you very much for this. I appreciate a lot. I will try to implement this on my php file and I will let you know the result. Cheers.

Comment: works great thank you. Now working on callbacks.`var getid = options.$trigger[0].parentElement.id; alert(getid);` is printing the row ID. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the modification of the javascript used in your first example:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
  var oTable = $('#example').dataTable({
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "sDom": 'l<"H"Rf>t<"F"ip>'
  });
  $(document).contextmenu({
    delegate: ".dataTable td",
    menu: [
      {title: "Delete", cmd: "delete"},
      {title: "Edit", cmd: "edit"}
    ],
    select: function(event, ui) {
        switch(ui.cmd){
            case "delete":
                $(ui.target).parent().remove();
                break;
            case "edit":
              $(ui.target).html(
                $('<input type="text"/>').val(
                  $(ui.target).text()
                ).bind( "keypress focusout",function (e) {
                  if (e.type=="keypress"?(e.keyCode ==13?true:false):true) {
                      $(this).parent().html(
                        $(this).val()
                      );
                    }
                  })
              );
                break;
        }
    },
    beforeOpen: function(event, ui) {
        var $menu = ui.menu,
            $target = ui.target
        ui.menu.zIndex(0);
    }
  });
} );
```

The working example has been posted here:

http://live.datatables.net/munonapo/1/embed

Comment: Thank you for this. How can I retrieve the id on click so, my php sends the correct id on delete/edit request. here I inserted your code in the jsfiddle that I prepared for David. http://jsfiddle.net/0f9Ljfjr/899/ the right click doesn't seem to be working though.

Comment: That's because it uses Jquery ui and dataTable scripts.You will have to embed them.

Comment: I created a new jsbin based on yours can you have a look please still doesn't seem to be working. http://output.jsbin.com/secunohivo